# Spring 3.0 REST service 401 Unauthorized

Tags: spring, proxy, resttemplate

I'm using RestTemplate from Spring 3.0. When I execute something like this:

```
 restTemplate.getForObject(url, Map.class);
```

I got:

```
 org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate- GET request for "http://somewhere.com..." resulted in 401 (Unauthorized); invoking error handler
```

That's cos I need to set up a Proxy address. How can I set a proxy with Spring RestTemplate?

This is what I did till now without any luck:

```
    HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("proxy.somwhere.com",9999);
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY,proxy);
    CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new    CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
    // requestFactory.getHttpClient().getHostConfiguration().setProxy("proxy.somwhere.com",9999);
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution above is perfectly working. It was a server side problem.